# o programa não lê a linha de arquivo que deveria ler

Tags: python

eu estou fazendo um programa q lê uma linha específica de um arquivo.txt para que eu possa então separar a linha e obter as informações. eu fiz essa função para saber em qual linha o CPF que foi digitado está localizado

```
def get_line(word):
    with open('alunos.txt') as alunos:
        for l_num, l in enumerate(alunos, 1): 
            if word in l: 
                return l_num
        return False
```

o arquivo "alunos.txt" tem informações assim:

```
nome do aluno 1,CPF,Semestre de ingresso
nome do aluno 2,CPF,Semestre de ingresso
...
```

aqui está outra parte do código:

```
cpf = input("\nDigite o CPF do aluno: ")

with open('alunos.txt') as alunos:
    for line in alunos:
        if cpf in line:

            posicao = int(get_line(cpf))
            
            inf = alunos.readlines()[posicao]
            #text = inf.split(',')  
            print(inf)
            break
    else:
        print("CPF não cadastrado\n")
```

o problema q eu recebo é o seguinte: quando eu digito o cpf q está na primeira linha do arquivo, ele retorna a terceira linha. e se eu digito qualquer outro cpf apenas dá erro... se eu dou um print na variavel "posicao" ele retorna o numero da linha certinho, mas quando eu vou ler usando o readlines() acontece esse problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você chama `readlines` **depois** de ter lido a primeira linha (quando você faz `for line in alunos`, a cada iteração do `for` uma linha é lida). Ou seja, a primeira linha já foi lida, e aí você chama `readlines`, só que como a primeira linha já foi lida, o resultado será **uma lista contendo da segunda linha em diante** (ou seja, o primeiro elemento é a segunda linha, o segundo elemento é a terceira linha, etc).

E como `get_line` retornou `1`, você tenta pegar o segundo elemento desta lista (pois listas são indexadas em zero: o primeiro elemento está no índice zero, o segundo no índice 1, etc).

---

Na verdade você está complicando à toa. Se você já está lendo o arquivo no `for line in alunos`, não precisa abrir o arquivo de novo na função `get_line`. Na verdade nem precisa desta função, dá para fazer tudo de uma vez:

```
cpf_busca = input("\nDigite o CPF do aluno: ")

with open('alunos.txt') as alunos:
    # itera pelas linhas do arquivo, juntamente com o número da linha
    for num, linha in enumerate(alunos, 1):
        # se quiser, pode separar os campos
        nome, cpf, semestre = linha.strip().split(',')
        if cpf == cpf_busca:
            print(f'CPF {cpf_busca} encontrado na linha {num}')
            break
    else:
        print("CPF não cadastrado\n")
```

Também usei [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) para remover a quebra de linha e [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) para separar os campos (mas se quiser, pode continuar usando `if cpf in linha`).